# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while connecting to S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-s3, illegalargumentexception

I have two instances of the same code , It works in a individual snippet which monitors a directory & uploads files to my s3 bucket using the credential in the below format :

```
access_keyID =prop.getProperty("access_keyID");

secret_access_key =prop.getProperty("secret_access_key");

AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_keyID,secret_access_key);

//S3 Client Creation

AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

But the same code fails when I integrate it to my main project & use it to transfer individual output files of the project to S3 bucket:

```
String access_keyID = Worker.access_keyID;

String secret_access_key = Worker.secret_access_key;

AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_keyID, secret_access_key);

//S3 Client Creation

 AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

With below Exception:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.impl.DefaultExceptionHandler: Consumer main.Worker$1@4bdae4da (amq.ctag-nFwSx5gpuh3V7OlfkF8Xow) method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel(amqp://new@127.0.0.1:5672/,1) threw an exception for channel AMQChannel(amqp://new@127.0.0.1:5672/,1):
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:134)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:95)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:42)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:345)
    at push.AWSFileUpload.fileUpload(AWSFileUpload.java:54)
    at rabbit.Cloudflare_Client.client(Cloudflare_Client.java:179)
    at main.Worker$1.handleDelivery(Worker.java:92)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.loadfrom(InternalConfig.java:199)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.load(InternalConfig.java:217)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.<clinit>(InternalConfig.java:252)
    ... 13 more
```

have tried & replaced every important jar to be same as individual snippet, still not working. Any useful help will be much appriciated, since I have run out of ideas.

Thanks